# Magento 2: installation command not working

Tags: installation, magento2.4, database-connection

I am executing magento 2 install command but it show error

[image: Base table not found]

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'magento_saas.store_website' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
> `main_table`.* FROM `store_website` AS `main_table` WHERE
> (main_table.website_id > 0)      ORDER BY main_table.sort_order ASC,
> main_table.name ASC

installation command

> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://magento2.com/
> --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento_saas --db-user=root --db-password=qwerty321 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200

Comment: Make sure db name and details are proper.

Comment: I have checked db details are fine

Comment: are you trying to install it on top of an existing magento installation?

Comment: I have got a git repo copy of project with minimum file base in app and composer.json

Comment: Try to install with composer or download source file from here https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and then try to install.

Comment: Already Done with composer install and even download new package and add repo code over there

Comment: Delete exiting database and create new one with same name and then try again.

Comment: Clear all of your existing db tables, disable all third party modules and rerun your install process.

Answer (score 2):

Found Solution for issue db need to be clean using  --cleanup-database attribute in installation command

> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://magento2.com/
> --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento_saas --db-user=root --db-password=qwerty321 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200 --cleanup-database